# How to get the correlation between two columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I have such a dataframe `df`:

```
time | Score| weekday
01-01-21 12:00 | 1 | Friday
01-01-21 24:00 | 33 | Friday
02-01-21 12:00 | 12 | Saturday
02-01-21 24:00 | 9 | Saturday
03-01-21 12:00 | 11 | Sunday
03-01-21 24:00 | 8 | Sunday
```

I now want to get the correlation between columns `Score` and `weekday`.

I did the following to get it:

```
s_corr = df.weekday.str.get_dummies().corrwith(df['Score'])
print (s_corr)
```

I am now wondering if this is the correct way of doing it? Or would it be better to create a new dataframe in which all the rows are first summed for each day by the `time` column and after this using the code above to get the correlation between `Score` and `weekday`? Or are there maybe other suggestions for improvement?

Comment: check out the pandas documentation on it: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.corr.html

in your case this would mean df['Score'].corr(other=df['weekday']) or something along those lines. It seems that your 'Score' columns is not float type, so maybe cast it to floats first.

Comment: Hmm, I do not think that this is the answer to my question. My code works, but I do not know, if it is the correct way of doing it.

Comment: I'm not sure what the correct way to go about this is, but you are looking for a correlation between a categorical variable (weekday) and a discrete(?) variable (Score). It might be best to look to [`scipy.stats`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/stats.html) for a suitable test, though I do not know which! There is a section on [correlation functions](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/stats.html#correlation-functions)

Comment: Hello Alex, yes, Score is a dicrete variable. I will check out your link. Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 1):

I have used [numpy.corrcoef](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.corrcoef.html) before for getting correlations between continuous and categorical variables. You can try it and see if it works for you:

I first created dummies for the categorical variables:

```
df_dummies = pd.get_dummies(df['weekday'], drop_first= True)
df_new = pd.concat([df['Score'], df_dummies], axis=1)
```

I then converted the DataFrame with the `dummies` to a `numpy array` and applied `corrcoef` on it likewise:

```
df_arr = df_new.to_numpy()
corr_matrix = np.corrcoef(df_arr.T)
```